# Killing a Process in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, multiprocessing, processing

I am new to this concept of MultiProcessing in python

I have this code

```
import os, time
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process


def square(number):
    """The function squares whatever number it is provided."""
    result = number * number

    # We can use the OS module in Python to print out the process ID
    # assigned to the call of this function assigned by the operating
    # system.
    proc_id = os.getpid()
    print(f"Process ID: {proc_id}")

    # We can also use the "current_process" function to get the name
    # of the Process object:
    process_name = current_process().name
    print(f"Process Name: {process_name}")

    print(f"The number {number} squares to {result}.")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # The processes list will store each call we make to "square" and the
    # numbers list contains the numbers we loop through and call the
    # "square" function on."
    processes = []
    numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    # Loop through the list of numbers, call the "square" function,
    # and store and start each call to "square".
    for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
        process = Process(target=square, args=(number,))
        processes.append(process)

        # Processes are spawned by creating a Process object and
        # then calling its start() method.
        process.start()

        if number == 2:
            process.terminate()
            time.sleep(0.01)
            print(process.is_alive())


        #print(process.is_alive())
```

So what happens I just want to check if a process is still alive. I am just confused cause I am calling the terminate function and if I remove the `time.sleep(0.01)` it returns True meaning the process is still ALIVE!

But when I put `time.sleep(0.01)` it prints out False! meaning the process is terminated right? So why is this `time.sleep(0.01)` a big thing? Am I missing out something? I'm sure there's something that I do not understand about this. But please feel free to tell me and if you would like to demonstrate a sample code for me to understand even better PLEASE BE MY GUEST I WOULD LOVE THAT!

Output when you include `time.sleep(0.01)`

```
False
Process ID: 1808
Process Name: Process-1
The number 1 squares to 1.
Process ID: 17180
Process Name: Process-3
The number 3 squares to 9.
Process ID: 2488
Process Name: Process-5
The number 5 squares to 25.
Process ID: 16656
Process Name: Process-4
The number 4 squares to 16.
[Finished in 1.0s]
```

If removed then

```
True
Process ID: 1808
Process Name: Process-1
The number 1 squares to 1.
Process ID: 17180
Process Name: Process-3
The number 3 squares to 9.
Process ID: 2488
Process Name: Process-5
The number 5 squares to 25.
Process ID: 16656
Process Name: Process-4
The number 4 squares to 16.
[Finished in 1.0s]
```

I really am fascinated by MultiProcessing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Processes are essentially telling python to run a new python instance with its own memory and everything. Which means there is a startup and shut down step that has to happen for each process, and this is not trivial. When you terminate and check immediately, there is not enough time for the process to actually terminate itself. The exact time needed is going to depend on your platform. This is an important part of multiprocessing, it's not always true that multiprocessing saves time. The overhead involved with each subprocess still has to be handled by the main thread.

Comment: Woow thank you for that wonderful answer! Sooo I was just checking if a process is still alive after it is done doing the things that the function it is assigned to. I searched about it that I can use the .is_alive() function and terminate()

Do you happen to know

Comment: Do you happen to know if what's the best way to check if it's alive? Thank you!

Comment: As far as I know is_alive is the only real way to know. It is not guaranteed to work, the process can die between the call to is_alive and the next line of code, it's one of the issues with multiprocessing. Depending on what your use case is, .join() will block execution until a process finishes. I use a queue to pass back a message that the data being processed by the process is ready and then I don't worry about the process itself